# How to make an I18N ChoiceList in Symfony2?

Tags: symfony, internationalization, symfony-forms, symfony-2.1

I'm extending [`SimpleChoiceList`](http://api.symfony.com/2.1/Symfony/Component/Form/Extension/Core/ChoiceList/SimpleChoiceList.html) to provide a `Gender` `<select>` to my user.

I'm wondering how I can make the label translatable.

For now, my code looks like:

```
class GenderChoiceList extends SimpleChoiceList
{
    public function __construct()
    {
        $choices = array(
            UserInterface::GENDER_MALE    => 'user.form.gender.label.male',
            UserInterface::GENDER_FEMALE  => 'user.form.gender.label.female',
        );

        parent::__construct($choices);
    }
}
```

Is there any way to make this work fluently or do I have to inject the `Translator` myself?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Labels are translated by default already. All you have to do is to put the translations into a `messages.LANG.FORMAT` file.

Comment: awesome, didn't know about that. Thank you. (*You can accept an answer in 2 minutes*, you'll have to wait ;))

Comment: Welcome. No worries, I'm not in a hurry. :)